# need jsPDF and html2pdf to create pdf and download it but no response

Tags: javascript, java, jspdf, html2pdf

I need to create a function that turns webpages into a pdf file, then download it after a click function.

My function is

```
$('<script src="/webroot/help/jspdf.min.js"></script>').appendTo('head'); 
$('<script src="/webroot/help/html2pdf.js"></script>').appendTo('head'); 
var jsPDF = window.jspdf.jsPDF;   
var pdf = new jsPDF('1','pt','a4');
pdf.canvas.height=72*11;
pdf.canvas.width = 72*8.5;
html2pdf($("div[widgetname=DC]"),pdf,function(pdf){
    pdf.save('file.pdf');
});
```

I checked no downloads nor errors msg.

Comment: `$("div[widgetname=DC]")` is not `html`, you need to use `$("div[widgetname=DC]").html()`

Comment: @FlashThunder I tried your code, nothing changed.